# Scipy linregress returns tuple when passed Pandas data

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

Using Pandas, I'm reading in data from a CSV file and then trying to perform a linear regression on it, using linregress. I am able to extract and manipulate the data from the file but, when I go to use linregress, while it seems to run the regression, it returns a tuple and seems not to have slope, intercept, and other attributes.

The error I am getting is below:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Plot test.py", line 24, in <module>
    UP_S_m = UP_S_stats.slope
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'slope'
```

With the following code:

```py
import csv
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import linregress

headers = ['UnitPrice', 'FinalPrice', 'ProductName', 'gSugar', 'gProtein', 'gFat', 'Calories', 'ContainerNum', 'Ounces']

data = pd.read_csv("Yogurt Sugar - All Data CSV.csv", names = headers, skiprows = 1)

UnitPrice = data.UnitPrice
FinalPrice = data.FinalPrice
Sugar = data.gSugar
Protein = data.gProtein
Fat = data.gFat
Calories = data.Calories
Ounces = data.Ounces

#
# Run regressions.
#

UP_S_stats = linregress(UnitPrice, Sugar)

UP_S_m = UP_S_stats.slope
```

I've looked through several examples, including [this very similar one](https://ourcodingclub.github.io/2018/04/18/pandas-python-intro.html), but can't identify where I'm going wrong.

Comment: ```slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x, y)``` ref: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html

Comment: Which version of `scipy` are you using?  You can find out with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in SciPy version 0.16.0, [`linregress`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) returns a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), which allows you to access elements of the tuple using attribute names.  If you are using a version SciPy older than 0.16, the return value is a plain tuple, so you will have to get the slope using regular indexing, e.g.

```
UP_S_m = UP_S_stats[0]
```

or unpack the names directly from the function call, e.g.

```
slope, intercept, rvalue, pvalue, stderr = linregress(UnitPrice, Sugar)
```